# iOS Safari not displaying button text

Tags: ios, reactjs, iphone, safari

I have some iOS users not all that are having issues seeing the text on on the button element for our react site. I was wondering if there has been a recent update that could be causing this odd functionality on some iOS devices.

One device is running an iPhone 12 and the other an iPhone 8.

The button styling is using bulma and the syntax look like:

<a className={'button is-primary' + (this.pageOptions.isProcessing === true ? ' is-loading' : '')}>Submit

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to use   `-webkit-appearance: none` on Button CSS

Safari's default button styling might be causing problem
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/appearance

Comment: I added an update and I don't know if this matters but im using bulma for the styling and added a sample button into the original question as well